# Using javascript to create a radio button html form, it keeps creating duplicate IDs

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Javascript to create an HTML form with radio button questions. The reason I am using JavaScript is that the questions take data from a google cloud firestore database, and they need to be dynamic. Here is my code:

```js
const splCanList = document.querySelector('#SPLInput');
const setupSPLCans = (data) => {
  let html = '';
  if (data.length) {
    data.forEach(doc => {
      const SPLCan = doc.data();
      const li = `
    <style>
    #SPLInput [type="radio"]:not(:checked), [type="radio"]:checked {
        position: static;
        opacity: 1;
        pointer-events: initial;
    }
    </style>
      <input type="radio" name="SplElection" id="SPL" value="${SPLCan.name}" style="display:block opacity:1;">${SPLCan.name}
      <br>
    `;
      html += li
    });
    splCanList.innerHTML = html;
  } else {
    splCanList.innerHTML = html;
  };
};
```

Whenever I try to send the answers to a database, it picks a random answer because the IDs are all the same. How do I make the IDs different for each answer and still just use 1 line to add the response to the database. I have put in **bolt** the spot where I need to have just 1 line.

```js
const voteForm = document.querySelector('#vote-form');
voteForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  db.collection('ballots').add({
   // **
    SPL: voteForm.SPL.value,
   // **

  }).then(() => {
    const modal = document.querySelector('#modal-vote');
    M.Modal.getInstance(modal).close();
    voteForm.reset();
  }).then(() => {
    const docRef = db.collection('users').doc(auth.currentUser.uid);
    docRef.get().then(function (doc) {
      doc.data().count++;
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: Inject something unique from each data item into the ID. Or append a counter which you increment each time around the loop.

Comment: Where it really should be "use the bits that uniquely identify _that_ radio button for the id", counters don't (think about it this way: if you reorder them in the DOM, resetting the id off of data that uniquely identifies a dom node doesn't change, whereas resetting it off of a counter now will, so a counter is _not_ a good id)

Answer (score 0):

remove the `id` attribute.
form elements don't need id to be acceded, they only need a name

as follow:

```js
<input type="radio" name="SplElection" value="${SPLCan.name}" style="display:block opacity:1;">${SPLCan.name}
```

and

```js
// *************
SPL: voteForm.SplElection.value,
// *************
```

Comment: That doesn't quite work. In the console, I got the error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined